# System.Array.IndexOf returns -1

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, system.array

I put a screenshot that will tell you everything.

```
    private Transform[] hiddenObjects;
void Start()
{
    leftImageRandom = new Randomizer(0, LeftImageSequence.transform.childCount - 1, true);
    DoStart();
}
private void DoStart()
{
    leftImageIndex = leftImageRandom.getRandom();
    LeftImageSequence.setCurrentChildIndex(leftImageIndex);
    RightImageSequence.setCurrentChildIndex(leftImageIndex);

    //take hidden objects and put them in an array
    hiddenObjects = RightImageSequence.CurrentChild.transform.GetChild(0).transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
    for(int i=1;i<hiddenObjects.Length;i++)
        hiddenObjects[i].gameObject.GetOrAddComponent<MouseEventSystem>().MouseEvent += ClickedHiddenObject;
    Debug.Log(hiddenObjects.Length);
}

private void ClickedHiddenObject(GameObject target, MouseEventType type)
{
    if (type == MouseEventType.CLICK && CanClick)
    {
        int targetIndex = System.Array.IndexOf(hiddenObjects, target.gameObject);
        Debug.Log(targetIndex);
        hiddenObjects[targetIndex].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().DOFade(1f, 0.3f).SetEase(Ease.Linear);
    }
}
```

I have a targetIndex that needs to return the index of the object I clicked on. Each object contains the PoligonCollider2D component. The problem is that it always returns -1 to any object. What's the problem, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: "I put a screenshot that will tell you everything." Please don't do that. Instead, post code *as text*, ideally in the form of a [mcve]. Fundamentally I'd expect the problem is that the array doesn't contain the element you're expecting it to. Given that your array is of `PolygonCollider2D` and you're trying to find a `GameObject`, that's not *terribly* surprising... perhaps you should have looked for the `PolygonCollider2D` part of target instead?

Comment: Okay, now I changed to Transform array, and the same thing

Comment: what is `target.gameObject` at runtime, when you execute the code?

Comment: the code is executed when I run Unity. The problem is that I've used it before, but I have not encountered errors

Comment: As almost allways the solution lies in using the debugger and see the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code:

```
private Transform[] hiddenObjects;
...
System.Array.IndexOf(hiddenObjects, target.gameObject)
```

`hiddenObjects` is an array of `Transform`, but `target.gameObject` is a `GameObject` (actually `target` is already a GameObject, so this is redundant): the types don't match, so indeed a `GameObject` is never gonna be equal to a `Transform`.

Instead try:

```
System.Array.IndexOf(hiddenObjects, target.transform)
```